# How to hide and show all the content of a div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, the div contains:

```
    <div id="choices">
            <ul>
                <li><button onclick="Correct('incorrect, try again!')">simple, easy</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="Correct('Correct! Congratulations!')">influence, advantage</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="Correct('incorrect, try again!')">premium, fine</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="Correct('incorrect, try again!')">contrary, opposite</button></li>

            </ul>
            </div>
```

I want to hide the content of this div completely with a function, and make it reappear with another function. Is that possible?

Comment: try $('#mydiv').hide() ; $('#mydiv').show() ;

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById('choices').style.display = "none"; //hide
document.getElementById('choices').style.display = "block"; //show
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to accomplish the task too. With it you can use some effects too. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/wZTs7/